# Thunderbird login issue

Tags: login, email, thunderbird

I have been using Thunderbird on my Dell Linux boxes for about 8 years now with no issues.

I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on a Dell Inc. XPS 15 9510. and run two email accounts through outlook.Office365.com for work.  This week I could no longer access my email through Thunderbird version 102.2.2 (64-bit).  I am getting the message "login to server outlook.office365.com with username XXXX@YYYY.com has failed"

I can login to my email through a browser but as I spend quite a bit of time off the grid I really prefer to use Thunderbird.  I have re-entered the email address as well as changed the password but neither of those things are working.

Any ideas?

Jay

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed that the people in charge of the work email account have not changed the security policy or otherwise disabled IMAP/POP access to the account? Another option may be to create an "application password" that is just for your Thunderbird client, which often survives across enterprise security changes 

Comment: Yes as I explained the situation and they gave me new passwords to try,

Comment: It's not just the username and password: also port number and encryption type need to match.

Comment: Turns out that Microsoft changed the password protocol from Normal to OAuth2

Never heard of that but it did the trick!